# Is there a set all three of them like?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

> I know three sisters who like sets, but they each have their own taste. I’m looking for a set that works for all three of them at once. Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R$.
>
> • Eliza likes $A$ if and only if it is not empty.
>
> • Angelica likes A if and only if $\exists x \in\mathbb R$ s.t. $\forall y \in A:y < x$.
>
> • Peggy likes A if and only if
>       $$
> \forall x \in A, \exists y \in A \cap (x, \infty)\text{ s.t. }\forall z \in\mathbb R: x < z < y \Rightarrow z \notin A.
> $$
>       Is there a set that all three of them like? If you think the answer is YES, construct
>       such set and explain why it works (you do not need a formal proof). If you think
>       the answer is NO, prove it.

Hello guys, I'm just starting to learn about logic and sets. And I've tried tackling the question above and I think my conclusions about the first two sisters are correct. However, I'm having a tough time understanding the set for the third sister.

This is what I've concluded about the first two:

- Eliza like any set that is not empty
- Angelica like any set that has an upper bound.

Could you guys please help me out? Moreover, if sombody could show me a correct way of answering this question it would be very helpful. thanks!

Comment: ... and Peggy likes the sets such that for all $x\in A$ there is $y\in A$ such that $x<y$ and the interval $(x,y)$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You mean $(x,y)\cap A = \emptyset$?

Comment: This is no reflection on the OP, but I have no idea what value the author of that exercise thought was being provided by formulating this exercise in terms of "sisters liking sets".

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes, I should have written "$(x,y)$ does not intersect $A$". My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have deciphered the first two correctly.

Notice that Peggy likes $A$ if and only if $\forall x \in A$ $\exists y \in A, y > x$ such that $(x, y)$ \cap A = \emptyset$.

Let's try $A = \left\{1- \frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$.

A is nonepmty, has an upper bound $1$, and indeed for every $x \in A$ there exists $y \in A$ greater than $x$ such that $(x,y)$ does not intersect $A$:

Take $x = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ and notice that the first element of $A$ to the right of $x$ is $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$. If we take $y = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$, we see that indeed $\langle x, y\rangle \cap A = \left\langle1 - \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right\rangle \cap A = \emptyset$, as there are no elements of $A$ between $x$ and $y$.

So, $A$ is liked by all three sisters.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand that the interval (x,y) does not intersect A but the interval [x,y] would intersect A , right?

Comment: @AndrewLee Yes. Indeed we have: $$\left [1-\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right] \cap A = \left\{1-\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right\}$$